Add outline which is not shown in rendered document
I am making a long .qmd-script containing plots in RStudio, and I want to have headings for me to navigate my script, however these headings should not be visible in the rendered document. If I make the headings inside my {r} chunks, then it wont be showed in 'Outline' in the right side of my script in RStudio, but if I make them outside the {r} chunks then the headings will be showed in the rendered document, which I do not want.
---
title: "Title of my document"
format: 
  html:
    self-contained: true
execute:
  echo: false
  warning: false
  message: false
---

# This heading will be showed in the outline (good) but also in the rendered document (bad) ####

```{r}

# This heading will not be showed in the outline (bad) and not in the rendered document (good) ####

library(dplyr)
...more code


Is there any way I can add headings for me to navigate via the 'Outline' function in RStudio in .qmd file, which will not be shown in the rendered document?
To be clear, when I write a normal R-script (.R) I add headings to navigate like this:
# 1. Heading ####
some code
## 1.1. Subheading ####
some more code

...which add this to the 'outline' section of the source pane:


What if you used comments?

how could I do that?

You could use the {.hidden} to the headers you only want to show in the outline of the document like this:
---
title: "Title of my document"
format: 
  html:
    self-contained: true
execute:
  echo: false
  warning: false
  message: false
---

# This heading will be showed in the outline (good) but also in the rendered document (bad) {.hidden}

```{r}

# This heading will not be showed in the outline (bad) and not in the rendered document (good) ####

library(dplyr)

```

Output document and outline:


just tried this and it seems it hides everything after {.hidden} including the plots which I produce in the {r} chunks. Is there maybe a way this tag should be ended?
